# New to Umbraco, where should i start?

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

im new to Umbraco , i have been looking for a book or cbt to start learning it but no hope ! , any one can point me to where should i start ?

any book ?!  any compelete material ? any place where i can start learning ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's multiple places, the most important one is: http://our.umbraco.org which features the wiki with a lot of articles.

Then there's the 5 free video's about Document Types (one of Umbraco's building blocks) at http://umbraco.tv/documentation/videos/for-site-builders/foundation/document-types

These videos also shows you all of the other sections that you will be accessing to create a simple website.

If your familiar with .Net usercontrols and want to use them in Umbraco, there's 5 more free video's about that at:
http://umbraco.tv/documentation/videos/for-developers/foundation/using-net-user-controls

For an example of how to install Umbraco easily, watch this screencast:
http://www.cultiv.nl/blog/2010/2/1/screencast-installing-umbraco (this is my blog and feature some other Umbraco articles that could be of use).

Comment: http://umbraco.com/help-and-support

Answer (score 1):

The official Umbraco page: http://umbraco.org/documentation

They have books, videos, the API documentation and a forum.  If you're willing to pay, they also offer professional training and certifications.

That page will keep you busy for a while.

Comment: Actually i was looking for something for free at the moment, but thanks any way

Comment: The documentation section is free.. But this is the old documentation, it has since moved to the wiki at: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki